# Cannot visit page directly in Nuxt SPA

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm using Nuxt `2.3.4`. I am using [vue-apollo](https://github.com/Akryum/vue-apollo) to query data for a `pages/_.vue` file to dynamically handle content. According to [this page](https://nuxtjs.org/guide/routing/#unknown-dynamic-nested-routes), this is the way to have dynamically nested routes. Everything works locally. However, when I copy my `/dist` folder, after running `yarn run build`, to my hosting server, I get a `404` error when I attempt to visit any pages other than `/` directly (e.g., `https://mysite.whatever/someurl/somenestedUrl`).

Based on [the nuxt router configuration docs](https://nuxtjs.org/api/configuration-router/#routenamesplitter) I have configured my `nuxt.config.js` to have the following setting:

```
/*
** Router
*/
router: {
    routeNameSplitter: '/'
},
```

Perhaps I need to configure my server `nginx` `.conf` file to handle these urls?

The below snippet is my `pages/_.vue` file.

```js
<template>
  <v-container v-if="!$apollo.loading && page">
    <v-layout>
      <v-flex
        xs12
        md9
      >
        <h2>{{ page.title }}</h2>
        <div v-html="page.content" />
      </v-flex>
      <v-flex
        id="sidebar"
        class="hidden-md-and-down"
        xs3
      >
        <h1>Sidebar</h1>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>
</template>

<script>
import * as R from 'ramda'
import gql from 'graphql-tag'

export default {
  name: 'Page',
  apollo: {
    page: {
      query: gql`
        query GetPageByUri($uri: String!) {
          pageBy(uri: $uri) {
            id
            pageId
            title
            date
            uri
            content
          }
        }
      `,
      variables() {
        return {
          uri: this.$route.params.pathMatch
        }
      },
      result({ data, loading, networkStatus }) {
        if (R.isEmpty(data)) return this.$router.replace('/404')
      },
      update(data) {
        return data.pageBy
      }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using ssr mode then u need to start nuxt server on server e.g. nuxt start and downstream from nginx to nuxt server. Example config could be found in [docs](https://nuxtjs.org/faq/nginx-proxy/)

If you are using SPA mode then you need redirect all queries to index.html via nginx like in this example  https://github.com/steebchen/nginx-spa/blob/master/nginx.conf